# Facebook Like API

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having some trouble with the facebook like api. I am creating the like button with the following code:

```
<fb:like href="http://www.nettunes.co.za/artist_profile.php?ref=fb&amp;amp;artist_id=<?PHP echo $row->artist_id;?>&amp;amp;show=albums&amp;amp;sub_section=song&amp;amp;id=<?PHP echo $row->song_id;?>" layout="box_count" show_faces="false" width="50" font="arial" title="<?PHP echo ucfirst($row->song_name);?> by <?PHP echo $row->artist_name;?> on www.nettunes.co.za"></fb:like>
```

I am then listening for the event and calling a javascript function, that ajax runs a piece of PHP that inserts the like into the local database to keep track of all likes for this artist. using this code:

```
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.type = 'text/javascript';
e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
e.async = true;
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        var song_id = response.toString().split("&amp;id=");
        likeSong(song_id[1]);
    });
```

The problem is that it doesnt always call this likeSong function and add the like to the database.

Has anyone had a similar problem before? or do you know of a better way of doing this?

thanks so much

take care,
Chregan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to wait for the Facebook library to be fully ready and check the response. You can do this with the `fbAsyncInit` method, which is called by Facebook once the library has loaded asynchronously:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId:"1234567890", status:true, cookie:true, xfbml:true, session:null});
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        if (response)
        {
            var song_id = response.toString().split("&amp;id=");
            likeSong(song_id[1]);
        }
    });
}

(function() {
var e = document.createElement("script");
e.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
e.async = true;
document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

You should also make sure that wherever likeSong is defined is initialized before the Facebook library loads and you add that event listener.